# How to attach my scrollbar to my listbox widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

here is a picture of what i want to be:

[scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JewWe.jpg)

Actual code:

```
lb = Listbox(self.master, width=120, height=6)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master, orient="vertical",command=lb.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
lb.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=lb.yview)
lb.place(x=5,y=5)
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox-scrolling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new frame with listbox and scrollbar in it:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')

frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(x = 5, y = 5) # Position of where you would place your listbox

lb = Listbox(frame, width=70, height=6)
lb.pack(side = 'left',fill = 'y' )

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical",command=lb.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

lb.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for i in range(10):
    lb.insert(END, 'test'+str(i))

root.mainloop()
```

or since you're using `place` (which is not recommended), you can simply calculate the position of the scrollbar. `grid` would be the best layout manager in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you use only the 'place' positioning, the scrollbar doesn't appear.
The solution is to make two frames - one master frame with a widget scrollbar and 
a second frame inside the master frame, where you can get the listbox. The frames can be positioned with place, the widget inside the frames with pack or grid. 
Below is my source code, what works perfectly.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.place(x = 10, y = 5,width=100,height=100) # Position of where you would place your listbox
frame1a=Frame(master=frame1)
frame1a.place(x=0,y=0,height=100,width=100)


lb = Listbox(frame1a, width=50, height=6)
lb.grid(row=0,column=0 )

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical",command=lb.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")


lb.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for i in range(10):
    lb.insert(END, 'test'+str(i))

root.mainloop()
```