# How to add scrollbars to this listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

Python V3.6, Windows 7, beginner 1 month.

I'm trying to work out how to add scrollbars to
a listbox, using tkinter.
can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

I have already tried to implement a similar answer from here:[How to attach my scrollbar to my listbox widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368559/how-to-attach-my-scrollbar-to-my-listbox-widget)  but I can't get that to work either.

```
    #listbox window
    edit_space = Listbox(
    master = top,
    selectmode   = 'single',
    width  = 53,
    height = 10,
    fg="blue")
    edit_space.place(x=10, y=130)
    edit_space.bind('<Double-1>', onselect)

    # add scrollbar to listbox
    #not working
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(edit_space)
    edit_space.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=edit_space.yview)
```

Comment: yes tkinter, I updated the question to reflect that and indented code again.

Comment: Your code really should be a [mcve], so we can run it & reproduce your problem. But I think I can see the cause of your problem.

Comment: here is full source code: https://pastebin.com/h21R7xNP

Comment: The program searches a drive or folder and sub-dirs for .txt files and searches inside them for the users search term.  Here is screenshot of program running: https://postimg.cc/image/ww8ox3ci9/

Comment: You should edit your original question to be minimal and complete, not add links into comments. The goal, as much as helping to get an answer to your question,  is to form a question that future readers can identify as  being similar to their problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you didn't tell Tkinter to display your Scrollbar, using `.pack`, `.grid`, or `.place`. But rather than just putting the ListBox and Scrollbar into the window it's neater to put them both into a Frame, so you can treat them as a unit. Here's a short demo derived from your code. I use the `pack` layout manager instead of `.place`, since it's easier to use & more flexible.

```
import tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()
top.title('Listbox demo')

def onselect(event):
    # Display the current selection
    idx = edit_space.curselection()[0]
    print(idx, edit_space.get(idx))

# Make a Frame to hold the Listbox and its Scrollbar
frame = tk.Frame(top)
frame.pack()

# Add the listbox
edit_space = tk.Listbox(top, selectmode='single', width=20, height=10, fg="blue")
edit_space.bind('<Double-1>', onselect)

# Add the Scrollbar
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(top)

# Pack the Scrollbar first so that it doesn't disappear 
# when the window width is small
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
edit_space.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Connect the Scrollbar to the Listbox
scrollbar.config(command=edit_space.yview)
edit_space.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# Put some data into the Listbox
for i, c in enumerate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    edit_space.insert(tk.END, '{:2}: {}'.format(i, 3 * c))

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you PM. I 'll try and see if I can integrate this with my code.